# Xpath query to step backwards in a path

Tags: java, xml, xpath

As a novice in Xpath and Java, I've been given the below sample xml. I'm trying to fetch `thickness` values of each `wall` element. `wall` elements **either** have them already in `const`, which I easily managed to get, **or** have their `const` referenced to another `wall` element (in this case the first `wall`).

I can get the `reference` attribute's value, but since I'm doing a query from the root  each time `xpath.evaluate((//node1/wall)[i]/*/thickness/node(),new InputSource(new FileReader(inputPath)),XPathConstants.NODESET`), I'm not able to step backwards trough the path.

The `reference` attributes also vary in depth in real scenario, so it's **NOT** always the "first" `wall` that the reference points to.

I tried getting the parent nodes and make a path list but was not successful.
Is there any workaround? Tnx in advance.

```
<node1>
  <wall>
    <const>
    <thickness>100</thickenss>
   </const>
  </wall>
   .
   .
   .
   <wall>
    <const reference="../../wall/const"/>
   </wall>
</node1>
```

Answer (score 0):

If ever the "reference" attribute doesn't contain the thickness or doesn't exist, you can catch the parent node, look for the first "wall" node and return the thickness.

Comment: The problem is it's not always the "first" wall that the "reference" points to in real case.